# How to install RabbitMQ erlang client on Windows

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

Im a newbie and i want to use RabbitMQ client for erlang.
I've downloaded the .ez file, and so what's next ?

should i unzip it and put the .beam files in my project's folder and call from there ?

or is there a package-manager of some sort that would do this automatically ?

Thanx

Comment: why don't you use the windows installation? 
http://www.erlang.org/download.html

Comment: Stupid question but... You are trying to do what from which programming language? Every language has a library, perhaps if we understood a bit more about what you are trying to do and how we could give you better direction. Or are you just playing around with it? Even if that is the case, what is the programming language you are using? RabbitMQ on it's own is like having a drivetrain sit on your desk, on it's own it won't do anything interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically all you need is to point your ErlangVM to place where `*.beam` files are. You can do it with `-pa [folder]` flag.

You might be already using this flag with `ebin` folder for your compiled source files, if you fallow standard OTP project structure. And then what most developers do, it to create `deps` folder where they keep all dependent applications, and adding additional `-pa deps/*/ebin` flag to `erl`.

And there is one quite standard build tool in Erlang world [called `rebar`](https://github.com/rebar/rebar/).  It is also used for managing dependencies (downloading them and compiling) but it doesn't seem that rabbit-erlang-client is compatible with it. You could still use it for compiling your own code, you just would have to compile rabbitmq-elang-client yourself with `make` (only once of course).

Comment: thank you for the clarification. What i want to do is to call up the .beam files from my module. i guess im confused on how to install it since the client is in .ez file and i thought there must be some kind of "pip install" equivalent where the client would be automatically loaded into the erlang runtime. so that i could call from there. but obviously it is not the way in erlang.